# Spring Data Neo4j 4.0 Gradle Dependency

Tags: spring, gradle, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to download the Spring Data Neo4j 4.0 tests dependency with Gradle, but it doesn't seem to work.
In the official tutorial documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.M1/reference/pdf/spring-data-neo4j-reference.pdf), only maven dependency below is provided:

```
<dependency> 
   <groupId>org.neo4j.ogm</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-testutils</artifactId>
   <type>test-jar</type>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-tests</artifactId>
   <type>test-jar</type>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

How to translate that to gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The neo4j-ogm-test artifact was not fully published in M1, but it is available. You will need to set the following gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
   testCompile(group: 'org.neo4j', 
               name: 'neo4j-ogm-test', 
               version: '1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT', 
               classifier: 'tests')
} 
repositories {
   maven {
     url 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-continuous-local'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Vince. 
Ok, so the latest version is 1.0.0. I thought there would be the 4.0.0 version. 
Actually, by the time I downloaded the SDN4 dependency, the neo4j-ogm-test 1.0.0.M1 has been included automatically. So, do I still need this 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version?

Comment: In this case they are the same artifact. The snapshot build is the latest version - but it just hasn't changed since M1.

Answer (score 2):

This should work (not tested)

```
dependencies {
       testCompile(group: 'org.neo4j.ogm', name: 'neo4j-testutils', version: '4.0.0.M1', classifier: 'tests')
}repositories {
     maven {
         url 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot'
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.

The one you just gave doesn't seem to work properly. The dependency has red underline here in my IntelliJ IDEA and there is a message which says 'unindexed remote maven repositories found'.

Second thing, for the other spring-data-neo4j-tests dependency, I specify it with :
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-neo4j', version: '4.0.0.M1', classifier: 'tests' and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Right, sorry, it should be 4.0.0.M1. Snapshot was my local version. Edited.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still doesn't work for the org.neo4j.ogm dependency, even after changing the version to 4.0.0.M1.

In the 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot', I can't find any ogm with 4.0.0.M1 version.

P.S.: Just saw your next comment. It also doesn't work with the new maven url. I can't find any 4.0.0.M1 version in that repo. There's only 1.0.0.M1.